# How to convert a column of timestamps HH:MM:SS.xxxxxxx to milliseconds?

Tags: python, timestamp

I have been trying to figure out how to do this in Python for the better part of a week, but not been able to find anyone to specifically answer this question. I have a log file, where every line is a timestamp with an event, as such:

```
HH:MM:SS.xxxxxxx   \t    Event
HH:MM:SS.xxxxxxx   \t    Event
HH:MM:SS.xxxxxxx   \t    Event
...
```

I have managed to put all this into a list, and figured out how to manipulate that list. What I haven't been able to figure out is how to convert the timestamp (which starts at 0 (well, at one second, really, but roughly 0)) into milliseconds (something I can do in Excel). So every timestamp just represents elapsed time, not an actual o'clock. The seven x's at the end make no sense to me at all, so not sure what they are.

Does anyone have a code snippet that I can use to convert this timestamp into milliseconds?

Comment: *"Does anyone have a code snippet that I can use"* isn't really an appropriate SO question. If you've been working on this for more than a week, where's your code and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Are they in your list as strings? You should seriously consider the `pandas` library for manipulating data of this nature. It makes reading it in and saving it out a breeze as well. Also, some examples of actual code you've tried and perhaps a sample of your data would help this question gain more traction.

Answer (score 2):

Are the seven x's seven actual x's or are they the format representation of fractions of seconds ?
If the accuracy of your input data is only down to seconds, I can't see how you can compute differences to milliseconds.

I suggest you read the documentation on time handling in python (datetime etc)

From which I cobbled together the following :

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

Set up 2 time strings - hopefully like the ones' you've got.

```
>>> times1="12:45:31.123456"
>>> times2="12:45:31.654321"
```

Use datetime.strptime to convert them into time objects

```
>>> timet1 = datetime.strptime(times1,"%H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> timet2 = datetime.strptime(times2,"%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Subtract them to get a time delta

```
>>> t_delta = timet2 - timet1
>>> str(t_delta)       
'0:00:00.530865'
```

Note : I had to omit the 7th digit from the time string (assuming they're not x's) as strptime would only accept 6 characters for microseconds (sensibly enough). If they are actual x's just use '.xxxxxxx' at the end of the format string for strptime and datetime will happily throw them away for you.
If you want to convert the seconds, minutes and hours in your difference to milliseconds, you'll have to work directly on the time object tuple. (see docs for datetime and many other SO threads)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, if the time stamp is a datetime.datetime.now() formatted one, then you would get it from the .microsecond.

Time = datetime.datetime.now()

print Time.microsecond

would give you more time scoping, to the microsecond level.